# Column size of Google Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am populating the data from server to google big query. One of the attributes in the table is a string that has close to 150+ characters in it.

For example, "Had reseller test devices in a vehicle with known working device
Set to power cycle, never got green light Checked with cell provider and all SIMs were active all cases the modem appears to be dead,light in all but not green light".

Table in GBQ gets populated until it hits this specific attribute. When this attribute is about to load, this does not get loaded in the single cell. It gets splitted into different cells and it corroupts the table.

Is there any restriction on each field of the GBQ? Any information regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you populating the table? If you could provide a [mcve] showing exactly what you're doing, that would really help. Note that if you're using a CSV upload, the fact that your value has commas in could easily be relevant...

Comment: As per https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-bigquery, the limit for a string is 2MB when encoded as UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that quote and comma characters in the CSV data are confusing the CSV parser.  For example, if one of your fields is `hello, world`, this will look like two separate fields. The way around this is to quote the field, so you'd need `"hello, world"`. This, of course, has problems if you have embedded quotes in the field. For instance if you wanted to have a field that said `She said, "Hello, world"`, you would either need to escape the quotes by doubling the internal quotes, as in `"She said, ""Hello, world"""`, or by using a different field separator (for instance, `|`) and dropping the quote separator (using `\0`).

One final complication is if you have embedded newlines in your field. If you have `Hello\nworld`, this means you need to set the allow_quoted_newlines on the load job configuration. The downside is that large files will be slower to import with this option, since they can't be done in parallel.

These configuration options are all described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.load), and can be used via either the web UI or the bq command line shell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a limit imposed, and certainly I have seen string fields with over 8,000 characters.

Can you please clarify, 'When this attribute is about to load, this does not get loaded in the single cell. It gets splitted into different cells and it corroupts the table.'? Does this happen every time? Could it be associated with certain punctuation?